# Tridion publish or unpublish error

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am getting following error in publishing or unpublishing a page. I want to delete this page but "delete" option is grayed out, trying to unpublish but getting error, Other pages are publishing fine. I chnaged the page template to a different page template but same error, tried to chnage component presentation but same error, If i run page template in Template builder block I get no error.

> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-56883-66560, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13

following is the log info

CD_deployer

> ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-56880-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-56880-66560, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:120) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:99) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_45]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_45]

Publisheer log

```
> 04:57:01.8353 <21112> Cache statistics: SimpleCache: 6 Regions, 6 Objects, 12 Hits, 5 Misses
04:57:01.8373 <21112>   Region 'Component': 0 Objects, 0 Hits, 0 Misses.
04:57:01.8392 <21112>   Region 'PublishTransaction': 3 Objects, 5 Hits, 1 Misses.
04:57:01.8402 <21112>   Region 'PublicationTarget': 1 Objects, 1 Hits, 1 Misses.
04:57:01.8412 <21112>   Region 'Page': 1 Objects, 1 Hits, 1 Misses.
04:57:01.8422 <21112>   Region 'Publication': 1 Objects, 5 Hits, 1 Misses.
04:57:01.8441 <21112>   Region 'Tdse': 0 Objects, 0 Hits, 1 Misses.
04:57:01.8509 <2708> Receiving deployment feedback for publish transaction [tcm:0-56881-66560] with status: WaitingForDeployment
04:57:01.9076 <20176> Deleting queue message: 286524 from PublishQueue.
04:57:05.2065 <2708> Transport service response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TransportSummaries>
    <TransportSummary state="Committing deployment" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.670+10:00" referenceId="tcm:0-56881-66560">
        <Processing>
            <Context topic="Content Delivery">
                <IsRollbackOnFailure>false</IsRollbackOnFailure>
            </Context>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.670+10:00" type="Prepare transport" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.690+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.670+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.690+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.699+10:00" type="Transporting" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.733+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.699+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.733+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.113+10:00" type="Deployment preparation" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.145+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.113+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.145+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.152+10:00" type="Deploying" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.195+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.152+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.195+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Committing deployment" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.198+10:00" type="Deployment committing" href="simple">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Committing deployment" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.198+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
        </Processing>
    </TransportSummary>
</TransportSummaries>

04:57:05.2524 <2708> Receiving deployment feedback for publish transaction [tcm:0-56881-66560] with status: CommittingDeployment
04:57:14.7440 <2708> Transport service response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TransportSummaries>
    <TransportSummary state="Failed" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.670+10:00" referenceId="tcm:0-56881-66560" end="2014-10-13T14:57:12.804+10:00">
        <Processing>
            <Context topic="Content Delivery">
                <IsRollbackOnFailure>false</IsRollbackOnFailure>
            </Context>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.670+10:00" type="Prepare transport" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.690+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.670+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.690+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.699+10:00" type="Transporting" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.733+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:01.699+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:01.733+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.113+10:00" type="Deployment preparation" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.145+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.113+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.145+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.152+10:00" type="Deploying" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.195+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Success" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.152+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:03.195+10:00" connector="HTTPS"/>
            </Step>
            <Step state="Failed" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.198+10:00" type="Deployment committing" href="simple" end="2014-10-13T14:57:12.804+10:00">
                <RemoteEndpoint windowSize="0" state="Failed" start="2014-10-13T14:57:03.198+10:00" processor="17012@otwtridonsql01" name="IIS" id="5e50QEKIyw3FuxiDAQw80Q==" end="2014-10-13T14:57:12.804+10:00" connector="HTTPS">
                    <Message>Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-56881-66560, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-56881-66560, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13</Message>
                </RemoteEndpoint>
            </Step>
        </Processing>
    </TransportSummary>
</TransportSummaries>
```

Comment: Also share the Java version installed on the Server. You may check by running java -version on the command prompt

Comment: java version "1.6.0_45"

Answer (score 3):

This indicates a problem with the deployment of the publish transaction (so it goes wrong on the content delivery side of the solution not on the content management side).

Troubleshooting such issues can be a difficult process especially "over the wire" like you are asking us to do here...

I will limit my answer to general guidelines on how to troubleshoot deployer issues:

1. Does this happen for all pages that you unpublish? Across all publications? Or only for some page? What makes this page "special" compared to others (if applicable)?
2. Does this happen always or is it a random occurrence?
3. Are there any non-standard extensions to the storage mechanism or the deployer? Does disabling these solve the problem?
4. How do your storage and deployer configuration compare to the "default" configuration supplied as samples as part of the Tridion installation sources?
5. Have you enabled debug logging of the deployer application? This usually reveals additional information about what it is doing when the error occurs...
6. Does the "lib" folder of your deployer application have all of the libs that Tridion provides in the Tridion installation sources for this role?

Usually problems of this nature revolve around either
- incorrect configuration settings in the storage configuration
- missing/incorrect jar files in the lib folder